Deny default route to BGP peer
I've a situation where i want to stop the default route(0.0.0.0/0) from sending out to a specific BGP peer.(EBGP peering)
I was working on Juniper EX-series
Example:
B(AS 2) is connected to A(AS 1) and C(AS 3), From "B" the default route must be advertised to "A" but not to "C".
I want to write a standard Policy statement on "B", which can be applied to both neighbors, but in the end, it should work as I expected by not sending the default route to "C".
I tried to configure the "Export" policy using "as-path-neighbors" like below but it's not working out:
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_default_out from route-filter 0.0.0.0/0 exact
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_default_out from as-path-neighbors as-list To_REMOTES ==> 1-9 AS
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_default_out then accept
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term deny_default_out from route-filter 0.0.0.0/0 exact
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term deny_default_out from as-path-neighbors as-list To_CDC (AS 10)
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term deny_default_out then reject
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_all then accept


Can you please someone help me out on how I can achieve this?
Thanks & regards

NOTE: If you post your BGP configuration for these two peers, I can probably provide a better answer ("show configuration protocols bgp | display set").
First, note that "from" and "to" statements are not a directionality thing, "from" is the equivalent of "I want to match this condition" and "to" is basically only used for redistributing between IS-IS levels. A few exceptions for directional matching would be things like "from source-address-filter", etc.
Junos BGP policy can be applied at:
# The protocol level 
set protocols bgp export EXP-POLICY

# The group level 
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS export EXP-POLICY

# The neighbor level
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS neighbor 1.1.1.1 export EXP-POLCY

The "most specific" policy is what is actually used, so if you had the same policy applied to the group and to a neighbor, the neighbor's policy would take precedence for that neighbor. If you had other neighbors in the same group, with no policy applied, the group level policy would take precedence.
Now, what you actually want to do given you have neighbor-specific policy conditions is to build the neighbor-specific policy and apply it to each neighbor. This will also make future policy changes far less risky. For example:
## The "static" bits are just an example, you'd have to check the source protocol and match with that if you want.

# AS-1
set policy-options policy-statement ADVERTISE-DEFAULT term DEFAULT from protocol static
set policy-options policy-statement ADVERTISE-DEFAULT term DEFAULT from route-filter 0.0.0.0/0 exact
set policy-options policy-statement ADVERTISE-DEFAULT term DEFAULT then accept
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS neighbor 1.1.1.1 description AS-1
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS neighbor 1.1.1.1 export ADVERTISE-DEFAULT

# AS-10
set policy-options policy-statement REJECT-DEFAULT term DEFAULT from protocol static
set policy-options policy-statement REJECT-DEFAULT term DEFAULT from route-filter 0.0.0.0/0 exact
set policy-options policy-statement REJECT-DEFAULT term DEFAULT then reject
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS neighbor 2.2.2.2 description AS-2
set protocols bgp group EBGP-PEERS neighbor 2.2.2.2 export REJECT-DEFAULT

Lastly, you may notice that I didn't add a term to "accept" the rest of the routes. Junos has protocol-specific default actions for policies, see here. That said, I personally do tend to add something like this to make things explicitly clear to other operators:
set policy-options policy-statement ACCEPT-ALL term ACCEPT then accept

If you need further clarification, I'll be happy to update my answer.

Does either of below work?
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_default_out to neighbor <ip_of_A>
set policy-options policy-statement test_out_1 term match_default_out to as-path [1-9]


Nope.., it's not working

The "to" and "from" statements are not a directionality thing, I'll post an answer shortly.
